# Usage of a correct collection Type

Tags: c#-4.0

I am looking for a **native**, or a **custom-type** that covers the following requirements:

- A  **Generic collection** that contains only unique objects like a `HashSet<T>`
- It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`
- It implements `IENumerable<T>` (duh) and must be wrappable by a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`    (duh, duh)
- It should work with **both small and large numbers** of items (perhaps changing inner behaviour?)
- the signature of the type must be like `UniqueList<T>` (like a list, not a key/valuepair)
- It does **not** have to be sortable.
- Searchability is **not** a "must-have".

The main purpose of this is to set up a small mesh/network between related objects.
So this network can only unique objects and there has to be a mechanism that notifies the application when changes in the collection happen.Since it is for a proof-of-concept the scope is purely within the assembly (no db's or fs are of any importance).

What is a proper **native type** for this or what are the best ingredients to create a **composite**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could just wrap `HashSet<T>` in your own type extremely easily, just to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You can easily proxy everything you need - e.g. `GetEnumerator` can just call `set.GetEnumerator()` etc. Implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` should just be a matter of raising the event when an element is added or removed. You probably want to make sure you don't raise the event if either you add an element which is already present or remove an element which *isn't* already present. `HashSet<T>.Add/Remove` both return `bool` to help you with this though.

I *wouldn't* call it `UniqueList<T>` though, as that suggests list-like behaviour such as maintaining ordering. I'd call it `ObservableSet<T>` or something like that.

Comment: WOW! Add() returns a bool! that completely solves my problem, I really was believing it was returning void.. must..read..better.. thanks! That makes it a lot easier. I almost started writing the whole thing from scratch. I'll keep the naming in mind ;)